# Spring security JWT refresh token not expiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, refresh-token

i am new to spring and i'm working on spring boot REST with spring security and currently I implemented JWT token. I have some questions but can't seem to find an answer to them. I tried adding a refresh token.
At first i thought i will store it in database with user, but spring security does everything automatically and i can't seem to find how to store it at a given field of table user.
So, moving on i decided i will try sticking with spring security automation and I set refresh token expiration time to 10 seconds to test if it expires, but sadly it does not work as intended - I can use refresh token for as long as I want and generate new tokens with it.
So here I have a couple of questions:
1. How do i make refresh token expire after given time? Here's my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${security.signing-key}")
private String signingKey;

@Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
private Integer encodingStrength;

@Value("${security.security-realm}")
private String securityRealm;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().httpBasic()
            .realmName(securityRealm).and().csrf().disable();

}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    defaultTokenServices.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(10);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}
```

}

2. Is it possible to pass refresh token to database and manually check if token is valid, because that was my first idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did find an answer, just forgot to update my ticket. So here it goes, by default JwtTokenStore does not support refresh tokens. [Here's JwtTokenStore source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtTokenStore.java).
So what this means, is that enabling token in settings, won't actually make it work. What i did, was create my own JWT token store that extends JwtTokenStore and write my own refresh token logic.

```
public class MyJwtTokenStore extends JwtTokenStore {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public MyJwtTokenStore(JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer) {
    super(jwtTokenEnhancer);
}

@Override
public void storeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    String username = authentication.getUserAuthentication().getName();
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
    user.setToken(refreshToken.getValue());
    userRepository.save(user);
}

@Override
public OAuth2RefreshToken readRefreshToken(String token) {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.readAuthentication(token);
    String username = authentication.getUserAuthentication().getName();
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
    if (!token.equals(user.getToken())) {
        return null;
    }
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = new DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken(token);
    return refreshToken;
}

@Override
public void removeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken token) {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.readAuthentication(token.getValue());
    String username = authentication.getUserAuthentication().getName();
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
    user.setToken(null);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

}

After this, i just updated my TokenStore Bean

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    MyJwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore = new MyJwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    return jwtTokenStore;
    // return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}
```

And at the end I added remaining settings to my AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter class to support refresh token and give it time of validity.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Value("${security.jwt.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${security.jwt.client-secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${security.jwt.grant-type}")
private String grantType;

@Value("${security.jwt.grant-type-other}")
private String grantTypeRefresh;

@Value("${security.jwt.scope-read}")
private String scopeRead;

@Value("${security.jwt.scope-write}")
private String scopeWrite = "write";

@Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
private String resourceIds;

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private AppUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
            .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType, grantTypeRefresh).scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
            .resourceIds(resourceIds).autoApprove(false).accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800) // 30min
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(86400); //24 hours
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter).tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*"); // http://localhost:4200
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

}